# C++ : output dynamic information to the log at compile-time

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to output dynamic information to the compiler output during compilation?

A more concrete example (C++11):

```
static_assert(sizeof(A) == 4, "Wrong size of A");
```

I would like to output the value of `sizeof(A)` when the assertion fails (or even always), but the message in [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) can't contain any dynamic information.

Is there any way to output the value of `sizeof(A)` to the compiler log?

Comment: Well, technically, `sizeof(A)` isn't particularly "dynamic", since it's known to the compiler. Right?

Comment: If it really were dynamic information the compiler wouldn't know it. So no, the compiler can’t output dynamic information, but there are tricks to make it print the static size of a type.

Comment: There is a proposal to allow constant expression `char const*`s instead of just string literals for the static assertion error message. Once that's accepted, you can compose own error messages and include formatted numbers, e.g. via [Constainer's printf](https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer/blob/master/StaticPrintf.hxx).